# DataList in ASP.NET is Printing with overlapped Columns?

Tags: asp.net, printing, datalist

Basically , I have  a Datalist which in my Browser & Print Preview look exactly how I need them to look , yet when I print the end 2 columns overlap and the page is missing half of my data off it. I know that this isn't a hardware problem as the Printer is used everyday at least 100 times so my issue here is with my Code. Here is my code , I have tried Width=% , Padding & Declaring Pixels of the columns etc but none of my methods affect the outcome , I can't use the  ' Overlay="Auto" ' as I can't print a scroll bar.

I know this isn't the most apt of details for a question on here & no doubt I will be punished for it but this is my last resort.

Thank you in advance for any answers that may guide me towards my goal. ( I need 15 rep to upload a picture of the final print if that helps )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon something like this , I did eventually find away to fix the problem at hand.